# azure powershell command to reduce or increase the VCores of a postgresql database in azure

Tags: postgresql, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have used the command, and I'm not able to get the expected result.

Update-AzPostgreSqlConfiguration -ResourceGroupName resourcegroupname -ServerName mydemoserver -Value SQL_STANDARD -Sku-name D2ds_v4

and got the error: 
[image]

I want the command to work and be able to reduce the VCores of my PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`Update-AzPostgreSqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.postgresql/update-azpostgresqlserver?view=azps-9.6.0) cmdlet which has the `-Sku` and `-SkuCapacity` parameters depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

@PramodValavala thank you for the answer but I already found the answer.